# Verification of the hashed password from the database with the user input in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, hash

Hi i am struggling with a problem the past days on the verification part of the user input password at log in. First to mentioned that i used an external library for codeigniter for the hashing of the password. The problem is when i get the hashed password from the database and use a library function that compares the raw password input of the user with the one from the database it returns false. I think i have tried and checked every possibility of error but i couldn't find an answer. I even checked if the lenght of the string was the problem, i tried also to change the lenght, the type(varchar,char) or even the collation of the password field in phpmyadmin but still no results. In my tries i thought that maybe there is a problem with the codeigniter library that i found so i decided to use the native php functions of brcypt in order to be sure. But the same problem consists at the point where the two passwords(hashed and raw input)are compared. I also tried just to hardcode the password then hash it and then compare the raw with the hashed one with the php verify function and surprisingly it returned true so i am confused what is going wrong and with the hashed password from the database it returns false but with the one that is been hashed and compared instanlty returns true. Both (codeigniter library and native php functions)work fine with way that are hashed and compared instantly. By the way just to mentioned it my php version is 5.6.10 I am at a deadend and out of ideas so any help will be appreciated guys.

[This is the library that i used](https://github.com/dwightwatson/codeigniter-bcrypt)

Everything is for test purposes so what i am providing is for testing if it works. My code is similiar

Test model that retrieves the hashed password and returns it to the controller in order to be compared with the hard coded password which is the same as the one provided on the register. Please ignore the comments

```
public function login_user($email){

    //Validate
    $this->db->where('email',$email);
    //$this->db->where('password',$enc_password);

    $result = $this->db->get('users');
    if($result->num_rows() == 1){
        $row = $result->row();
        }
        return $row->password;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Test controller

```
public function login()
{
    $this->load->model('test_model');
        $email = "minas@live.com";
        $password = '12345';

       $test1 = $this->test_model->login_user($email,$password);

    //$options = [
        //'cost' => 10,
    //];
    //$hash_password  = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT,  $options);


    if(password_verify($password, $test1)){
            $query_data['test']="it works";
        }else{
            $query_data['test']="not works";
        }


        //$this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('view_test2',$query_data);
        //$this->load->view('templates/footer_movie_list_full');
```

My hash when i am creating the user

```
    public function create_member(){


    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $options = [
        'cost' => 10
    ];
    $hash_password  = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);

    $new_member_insert = array(
        'firstname'       => $this->input->post('user_firstname'),
        'lastname'        => $this->input->post('user_lastname'),
        'email'            => $this->input->post('user_email'),
        'password'         => $hash_password
    );

    $insert = $this->db->insert('users', $new_member_insert);
    return $insert;
  }
}
```

For the validation i am using the set rules function of codeigniter which is executed before anything comes to the post that i am using in database.
Please help me as i am stuck as i don't know what else to do.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the github library you mentioned? Your `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` functions look like the built-in PHP functions to me. How big is your password column? It needs to hold at least 60 characters.

Comment: You have sufficient closing curly bracket before `return $row->password;`.

Comment: You are doing it right, but you have to delete the `}` from: `$row = $result->row();  }  return $row->password;` because the password is never returned.

Comment: @OllieJones this is the second way with the native php functions as i said that i already tried it with the library and thought that the library was the problem so i decided to use the native php functions. My column is 255 big.  I understand that there is a typo but i don't think that this is the reason why the compare or verify function is not working

Comment: As others have pointed out about the vurly braces, it is clearly a problem.  However for me I am wondering if you have provided us the exact code you are running. That is because this code should produce a php error as your else statement is dangling in you login_user function.

Comment: That curly brace was commented in my code thats why i am not getting an error. When i copied the code it did't show up so the curly braces are not the problem as it works normally. The problem is that when i am getting the hashed password from the database and compare it, it returns false but when i use the hardcoded one hash it and then compare it , it returns true which is the weird in this case.